# what does this bit of code in EventListenerList means in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, listener, event-listener

I came across this code. I want to understand what the  `fireStateChanged` method does and how it does.

```
public abstract class AbstractModel {

        private EventListenerList listenerList;

        protected EventListenerList getListenerList() {
            if (listenerList == null) {
                listenerList = new EventListenerList();
            }
            return listenerList;
        }

  protected void fireStateChanged() {
            ChangeListener[] listeners = getListenerList().getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
            if (listeners.length > 0) {
                ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
                for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
                    listener.stateChanged(evt);
                }
            }
        }

}
```

what this bit of code do differently than the `fireStateChanged` method above?

```
public void fireActionEvent(ActionEvent evt) {
            ActionListener[] listenerList = listeners.getListeners(ActionListener.class);

            for(int i = listenerList.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
                listenerList[i].actionPerformed(evt);
        }
```

I am a beginner for using EventListenerList. I read the docs also. but I am not clear what is going on. `fireAction` kind of methods commonly occur in many codes. so I want to understand this concept clearly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see only a simple difference. This code below extracts ChangeListeners and ChangeListeners only from the listener list, and then fires them:

```
protected void fireStateChanged() {
    ChangeListener[] listeners = getListenerList().getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
    if (listeners.length > 0) {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
        for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

While this one extracts only ActionListeners from the same listener list, and then fires them:

```
public void fireActionEvent(ActionEvent evt) {
    ActionListener[] listenerList = listeners.getListeners(ActionListener.class);

    for(int i = listenerList.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
        listenerList[i].actionPerformed(evt);
}
```

The two different types of listeners require different parameters in the methods that are fired when they are activated, and so the first bit of code requires that this Event object be created. In the second, they pass in the ActionEvent into all of the ActionListener, actionPerformed methods.

Comment: the first one above is 'changeListener []` and the other is `ActionListener[]`. can you explain what the code and where these will be useful?

Comment: @user1988876: please be more specific in your question. What confuses you?